# Network is down with eth0:0 over direct connection to PC

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, ethernet

I have headless rpi3.
I have problem when I connect RPi ethernet directly to PC. Network is going down after a while.
My /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.222/24
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I am able to use both eth0 and eth0:0 when I connect it to my router with:
192.168.2.35-> eth0
192.168.2.222->eth0.0.

After that when I connect RPi to my PC directly, I can reach RPi over 192.168.2.222 for a while than it is gone.
I dont know why. Why it is like that? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you REALLY want an Answer - you **CAN'T** "fix it" because this is how virtual network interfaces work.

If you read the documentation you will discover that you can only define a virtual network interfaces if the interface exists, which yours **WON'T** if not connected to a DHCP server.

There is also NO POINT in attempting to define a netmask (or CIDR notation) on a virtual network interface.